# Returning Values php

Tags: php

All i know from the return statement (based on JS) that is stops execution of the script and return the value and whats after it ignored, then how is that possible
(in fact required) in this php code :

```
<?php
return "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>$title</title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
</head>
<body>
$content
</body>
</html>";
```

which is completing this :

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
$title = "Test title";
$content = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
$page = include_once "templates/page.php";
echo $page;
```

and also is it possible to have return outside a function ????

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there...

With the template/page.php you don't need to run a return all you need to do is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'/>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $content; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Then within the PHP page side of things lets say for example, `phpCode.php`:

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );
$title = "Test title";
$content = "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
include_once "templates.php";
```

Include will pull all of the information from the file you're including generally.

You can pull information from anywhere providing you have required the php file. PDO / OOP is a great example of how to do this and I'd highly suggest learning it somewhat more to achieve what you're trying to do (from what I could make out in the question).

Comment: thanks a lot, i guess i'm gonna with your approach ,
that return is really confusing